# Use OData parameter $filter and $orderby operators in an rest API call

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

I am using API call to fetch news items from a custom list, and filter by its date and then orderby news item's title. 
However orderby clause never works, if I put $orderby before $filter, then filter clause stop working.

Here is my CAML query:

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'CE7A5EC9-D264-48D9-8F81-1C2F8C7341XX')/items?
$select=ID,Title,StartDate,Expires
&$filter=StartDate le datetime' + midnightDayIsoString + ' and Expires ge datetime' + midnightDayIsoString + '
&$orderby=Title
```

midnightDayIsoString is defined by using new Date() function, calling .toISOString() method, and replace the time parts with hardcoded 12:00:00Z.
e.g. datetime('2017-08-15T12:00:00Z')

API call is using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url:  siteurl + query,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
            RowLimit: null,     
            RowsPerPage: null,  
            success:onSuccess,
            complete:onComplete,
            error:onError
        });
```

The query returns correct filtered result, but does not do the $orderby part.

I don't know that why orderby is not working. I need some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: are you missing the `?` between `../items?$select=...`

Comment: Sorry that was my typo when I was entering the question, I will correct that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Can you show us your entire code including how you are deriving `midnightDayIsoString`?

Comment: I've just update the post with some code sample in there, actually quite standard.

Comment: Hi Guys, just letting you know that it works suddenly without changing things that I cannot explain. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the dates already as an ISO string, you don't need the datetime parser in REST.

Try:

```
var query = "/_api/web/lists(guid'CE7A5EC9-D264-48D9-8F81-1C2F8C7341XX')/items?
$select=ID,Title,StartDate,Expires
&$filter=StartDate le '" + midnightDayIsoString + "' and Expires ge '" + midnightDayIsoString + "'
&$orderby=Title";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
&$orderby=Title asc
or &$orderby=Title desc
```

If you didn't get expected results then try without filter in query like as bellow.

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'CE7A5EC9-D264-48D9-8F81-1C2F8C7341XX')/items?
$select=ID,Title,StartDate,Expires&$orderby=Title
```

If you got results in sorting order then you need check filter condition in URL.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tied this before, it worked. It was a bit strange when i put both $filter and $orderby parameter, then the results didn't get sorted. But just minutes ago, it starts working that I cannot explain why worked.